# Black screen on startup without upstart (Ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: boot, kubuntu, segmentation-fault

Currently when I try starting my computer in normal mode it will display the pulsating kubuntu logo and then a black screen will stay forever.

What I did to get here:
Installed Ubuntu 15.10, installed kde desktop right after.
I was playing around with compiling 64-bit and 32-bit stuff at the same time and in the process of installing 32-bit gcc or g++ or something like that it uninstalled some kde packages. It did warn me, yes. I take full responsibility for that. As I did not restart, the system ran fine for a few days until today it crashed and I restarted it. It did not boot to desktop, I got to enter my login and password to get a command line. It complained only about wine-staging:i386 being broken, kinda random, probably not relevant. So naturally I wanted to get rid of kde completely and get the defaults back so I installed ubuntu-dekstop. Restarted and that's it, black screen and nothing happens. But the strange thing is when I choose to boot with the upstart option it starts just fine. The question then is can I get normal boot to work again? And maybe get rid of the kubuntu logo on startup?

Comment: Forgot to add I was using a ppa to get a newer version of kde.
Tied installing kubuntu-desktop again, apt-get failed but aptitude made me a nearly 300-step installation. After running through all of it Ubuntu will not start at all anymore. Not even with upstart. In debug mode I used to get a terminal but even that doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Found this in /var/log/kern.log sddm-greeter[1670]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fc134c3f444 sp 00007ffe6d403380 error 4 in libxcb.so.1.1.0[7fc134c35000+20000]. It seems like a known issue with qt but I don't understand how it's fixed when the OS doesn't run.

Comment: i changed the contents of /etc/X11/default-display-manager to /usr/sbin/lightdm and I can start my system with the upstart option again. Normal boot does not work, cannot switch to plasma desktop. It will just say there was an internal error and go back to default desktop.

Comment: I've somehow ended up with libqt5x11extras5 version 5.5.1-1 that is known to cause segfaults. I need to either upgrade or downgrade it... somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue the correct version of libqt5x11extras5 needs to be installed.

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5x11extras5=5.4.2-2build1
```

5.4.2-2build1 is the correct version for Wily according to packages.ubuntu.com. Previously I had version 5.5.1-1 that caused segfaults.

The broken package is from Kubuntu-ppa Backports:
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/kubuntu-ppa_backports/wily/main/base/libqt5x11extras5

Comment: Upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS reproduces the issue and this solutions no longer works because the official version is broken. I recommend booting to a Unity session and removing the package and destroy the KDE install with it. That's what worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

hhmm, i386 broken......well that doesn't sound good at all. For a stable Desktop OS I'd honestly wipe it and install the most current Ubuntu LTS OS. Which is currently 14.04 until 16.04 releases (traditionally in late April and then again in October). While 15.10 is not LTS it is only supported for 9 months, it is expected to be buggy.

BUT if you do actually want to attempt to fix it start with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

first then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

secondly, then reboot lastly. That obviously updates and upgrades your os. If that doesn't help then try a more brute force attempt:

```
sudo history
```

That should (key word: SHOULD) house every command you've done in terminal. Which may help you isolate exactly what commands you ran, to figure out what commands to revert. This helped me isolate and fix issues with desktop not showing on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin.

IF you ran the commands as root (not recommended!!) you'll have to be root to see roots history. For that:

```
su -
```

login with your root PW 
then run:

```
history
```

If those don't help; let me ask, are you running the 64bit version of Ubuntu on a 64bit CPU? or 32bit os on 32bit cpu? or 32bit os on 64bit cpu? or 64bit os on 32bit CPU?

Good luck with taming the wily werewolf.

Comment: I've updated and upgraded several times already. It's 64-bit OS on 64-bit cpu. It's impossible to run 64-bit OS on 32-bit cpu btw. I really think it boils down to libqt5x11extras5 version, however things get tricky when package manager version doesn't work. I have another wily in a virtual machine, working perfectly and this trouble package is not installed. Uninstalling this package once kde is installed will break kde and therefore the whole system.